# How To Slow Down glutIdleFunc Animation Speed

Tags: c, opengl, animation

Dear all I am trying to create animation using OpenGL through `glutIdleFunc()`. Below is my code:

```
float t = 0.0;

void idle (void)
{
    t += 0.1;
    if (t > 2*pi)  
    { 
        t = 0.0; 
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

//in main function
glutIdleFunc(idle);
```

I have been trying to adjust the increment of t in order to slow down my animation. But somehow my animation keeps moving on too fast, until I can't catch it with my eye. Does anyone know how to slow down this kind of animation? Thank's

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to find an artificial `t` value to use in your idle function, you'll probably be better off using a real timer such as C's `time()`.  Then, simply advance your animation by the appropriate amount given the elapsed time since the last frame was drawn.

Here's how it might look:

```
time_t lastTime;

void draw() {
  const time_t now = time();
  const double dt_s = difftime(now, lastTime);

  // Update your frame based on the elapsed time.  For example, update an angle
  // based on a specified rotation rate (omega_deg_s):
  const double omega_deg_s = 10.0;
  angle += dt_s * omega_deg_s;
  angle = fmod(angle, 360.0);

  // Now draw something based on the new angle info:
  draw_my_scene(angle);

  // Record current time for next time:
  lastTime = now;
}
```

Comment: @rofansmanao:  Sure.  Just added one.  The key is to use rate information, rather than just absolute increment values.

Comment: GLUT has its own time getting function that works quite well too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the time since the last function call rather than a straight value as your metric, since that time may vary.
For more information, read [valkea's answer on GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/13011/11274), which suggests that you use `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)` to calculate that value.